# Создание аналога загрузчика сайтов HTTrack

Tags: java

Хочу написать аналог загрузчика сайтов HTTrack, который бы создавал на локальной машине полную копию сайта с сохранением структуры папок и файлов. Пока не знаю как подойти к решению этой задачи, решил посмотреть в сторону html парсеров и различных краулеров, но все равно пока общая концепция не ясна. Посоветуйте, как лучше подойти к решению данной задачи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте несколько потоков-воркеров, которые бы брали задачи на загрузку из очереди. В самом начале кладёте одну задачу на скачивание самое первой страницы.

Воркер берёт задачу из очереди и скачивает её. После скачивания если content-type = text/html, то смотрит каким-нибудь html-парсером и ищет все внутренние ссылки на ресурсы (картинки, другие страницы, скрипты, etc). Заменяет все пути к ним на локальные пути. Добавляет эти ресурсы в очередь на загрузку, если глубина загрузки не больше заданной пользователем. Если очередь опустела, то говорите что всё, конец.

Вот и вся программа.

Comment: а если вместо локальной копии (структура папок и файлов) использовать БД, каким образом лучше хранить данные (речь опять же идет о полной копии сайта)?

Comment: А зачем это делать? Ну вы можете сохранить все ресурсы и страницы в БД в виде блобов и клобов, но тогда их нельзя будет открыть просто так. Я просто не понимаю, зачем это делать? Вы хотите какие-то бэкапы там хранить? Почему в базе?